# how to create a socket.io service in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am seeing a little what is websocket with (socket.io), I have a question and a problem, what happens is that I would like to know how I can use (socket.io) in a service in background to be able to send messages outside the application, I have this code that I made in my MainActivity and it works fine, it connects to my socket.io server and sends the gps data but it only works in the foreground, when I exit the app it stops send messages I hope you can help me thank you very much.

here is the code..

```
private String mensaje;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLocation;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;


private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;
private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 200;  /* 10 secs */
private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000; /* 2 sec */

private LocationManager locationManager;

/////  SOCKET.IO /////////
public static String uniqueId;
private String Username = "ale";
private Boolean hasConnection = false;

private int time = 2;
private boolean startTyping = false;
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("https://stbuses.herokuapp.com/");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {}
}

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
Handler handler2=new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if(time == 0){
            setTitle("SocketIO");
            Log.i(TAG, "handleMessage: typing stopped time is " + time);
            startTyping = false;
            time = 2;
        }

    }
};
///////////////////////////////////////////

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listamensajes);
    editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editexmensaje);
     textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enviar);

     //////////// SOCKET.IO :::::::::::::::::
    uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        hasConnection = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasConnection");
    }

    if(hasConnection){

    }else {
        mSocket.connect();
        mSocket.on("connect user", onNewUser);


        JSONObject userId = new JSONObject();
        try {
            userId.put("username", Username + " Connected");
            mSocket.emit("connect user", userId);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    hasConnection = true;

    /////////////////////////////

    mensajeAdapter = new MensajeAdapter();
    listView.setAdapter(mensajeAdapter);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

/////////// SOCKET.IO ::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Emitter.Listener onNewUser = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int length = args.length;

                if(length == 0){
                    return;
                }
                //Here i'm getting weird error..................///////run :1 and run: 0
                String username =args[0].toString();
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(username);
                    username = object.getString("username");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
};


///////////////////////////

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    startLocationUpdates();

    mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if(mLocation == null){
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    if (mLocation != null) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String currentDateandTime = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    String msg =
            "linea2" + "," + "16" + "," +
            Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
            Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

    String message = msg;

    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject2.put("message", message);
        jsonObject2.put("username", Username);
        jsonObject2.put("uniqueId", uniqueId);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   mSocket.emit("chat message", jsonObject2);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (!msg.isEmpty())
    {
        //webSocket.send(msg);
        //mSocket.emit("chat message", msg);

        editText.setText("");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {

            jsonObject.put("mensaje",msg+" "+currentDateandTime);
            jsonObject.put("byServer",false);
            mensajeAdapter.addlista(jsonObject);
        }catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    // Create the location request
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    // Request location updates
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
            mLocationRequest, this);
    Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
}
```